# Sockets en misma red WiFi con python

Tags: python, python-3.x

me gustaría saber cómo puedo comunicarme de un ordenador a otro con sockets en Python, ya que muchos tutoriales en internet sólo se conectan al localhost.

Comment: Se conectan a localhost como un ejemplo, se debería poder cambiar localhost por la dirección de la PC en la que ejecutas el servidor (por ejemplo, 192.168.0.9).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resumen: Comunicarse con localhost o con cualquier otro host en la red es lo mismo. Toma cualquier ejemplo y sustituye 127.0.0.1 por la dirección del host que deseas; es todo el cambio que necesitas.

**¿Qué es localhost?**

La red TCP/IP usa direcciones IP (como 134.98.3.4) para identificar a las máquinas, y en principio es todo lo que que necesitas para comunicar dos máquinas entre sí (o consigo mismas incluso).

La dirección 127.0.0.1 (localhost) es la IP de la máquina en una red virtual interna. Asi, toda máquina puede tener un stack TCP/IP completamente funcional, incluso si no tiene ninguna interfaz física ni está conectada a nada.

Esto permite correr cliente y servidor en la misma máquina o en máquinas distintas sin tener que cambiar el código, sólo las IP.

Puedes usarla también para agregar seguridad a aplicaciones, haciendo que sólo escuchen conexiones en localhost, y por tanto, sean inaccesibles desde otras máquinas.

Esta dirección está garantizada de existir en todo equipo que tenga stack TCP/IP.

Comment: Y en vez de poner localhost que IP tendría que ingresar? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: @UnaPersona. Tienes que poner la IP del host con el cual deseas conectar.

Comment: Entonces si la IP del PC servidor es por ejemplo: 192.168.0.0 entonces en el PC cliente tendría que poner esa IP?

Comment: @UnaPersona. Correcto.